# LNK2028 LNK2029 when compiling static c++ library in managed c++/clr

Tags: c++-cli, linker-errors

As i am pretty much out of ideas and the google results by now have reached the point where they hit ~10 and less, i now turn here in hope of seeing the answer or at least a clue that leads me to the actual solution.

I am creating a project that can be distributed as executable, non-static library and static library.
I want to use the library in a WPF project (C#) which is why i created a simple CLR wrapper.

It all worked very well up until the most recent change introduced into the base-library.
Now, i get linkage errors (5 in total) on all calls to the "main" class in the library project:

```
1>wrapper.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0016EB) "public: class std::vector<struct sqf::diagnostics::stackdump,class std::allocator<struct sqf::diagnostics::stackdump> > __thiscall sqf::vmstack::dump_callstack_diff(class std::shared_ptr<class sqf::callstack>)" (?dump_callstack_diff@vmstack@sqf@@$$FQAE?AV?$vector@Ustackdump@diagnostics@sqf@@V?$allocator@Ustackdump@diagnostics@sqf@@@std@@@std@@V?$shared_ptr@Vcallstack@sqf@@@4@@Z) referenced in function "public: class std::vector<struct sqf::diagnostics::stackdump,class std::allocator<struct sqf::diagnostics::stackdump> > __thiscall SqfVm::wrapper::get_stackdump(void)" (?get_stackdump@wrapper@SqfVm@@$$FQAE?AV?$vector@Ustackdump@diagnostics@sqf@@V?$allocator@Ustackdump@diagnostics@sqf@@@std@@@std@@XZ)
1>wrapper.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0016F5) "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall sqf::virtualmachine::preprocess(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,bool &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?preprocess@virtualmachine@sqf@@$$FQAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V34@AA_N0@Z) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall SqfVm::wrapper::preprocess(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,bool &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?preprocess@wrapper@SqfVm@@$$FQAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V34@AA_N0@Z)
1>wrapper.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0016F6) "public: struct sqf::parse::astnode __thiscall sqf::virtualmachine::parse_sqf_cst(class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >,bool &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?parse_sqf_cst@virtualmachine@sqf@@$$FQAE?AUastnode@parse@2@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AA_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@6@@Z) referenced in function "public: struct sqf::parse::astnode __thiscall sqf::virtualmachine::parse_sqf_cst(class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?parse_sqf_cst@virtualmachine@sqf@@$$FQAE?AUastnode@parse@2@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@6@@Z)
1>wrapper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall sqf::virtualmachine::preprocess(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,bool &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?preprocess@virtualmachine@sqf@@$$FQAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V34@AA_N0@Z) referenced in function "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall SqfVm::wrapper::preprocess(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,bool &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?preprocess@wrapper@SqfVm@@$$FQAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V34@AA_N0@Z)
1>wrapper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: struct sqf::parse::astnode __thiscall sqf::virtualmachine::parse_sqf_cst(class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >,bool &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?parse_sqf_cst@virtualmachine@sqf@@$$FQAE?AUastnode@parse@2@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AA_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@6@@Z) referenced in function "public: struct sqf::parse::astnode __thiscall sqf::virtualmachine::parse_sqf_cst(class std::basic_string_view<char,struct std::char_traits<char> >,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >)" (?parse_sqf_cst@virtualmachine@sqf@@$$FQAE?AUastnode@parse@2@V?$basic_string_view@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@6@@Z)
1>wrapper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class std::vector<struct sqf::diagnostics::stackdump,class std::allocator<struct sqf::diagnostics::stackdump> > __thiscall sqf::vmstack::dump_callstack_diff(class std::shared_ptr<class sqf::callstack>)" (?dump_callstack_diff@vmstack@sqf@@$$FQAE?AV?$vector@Ustackdump@diagnostics@sqf@@V?$allocator@Ustackdump@diagnostics@sqf@@@std@@@std@@V?$shared_ptr@Vcallstack@sqf@@@4@@Z) referenced in function "public: class std::vector<struct sqf::diagnostics::stackdump,class std::allocator<struct sqf::diagnostics::stackdump> > __thiscall SqfVm::wrapper::get_stackdump(void)" (?get_stackdump@wrapper@SqfVm@@$$FQAE?AV?$vector@Ustackdump@diagnostics@sqf@@V?$allocator@Ustackdump@diagnostics@sqf@@@std@@@std@@XZ)
1>wrapper.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall sqf::virtualmachine::virtualmachine(class Logger &,unsigned __int64)" (??0virtualmachine@sqf@@QAE@AAVLogger@@_K@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall sqf::virtualmachine::virtualmachine(class Logger &)" (??0virtualmachine@sqf@@QAE@AAVLogger@@@Z)
1>D:\Git\SQFvm\clrBridge\Release\clrBridge.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
```

The projects, can both be found here:

1. The C++ Project https://github.com/SQFvm/vm
2. The C++/CLR Project https://github.com/SQFvm/ClrBridge

---

Was able to get rid of the LNK2028 issues by adding another separation layer (wrapper.cpp & wrapper.h) and then putting a `#pragma unmanaged` at the top of the cpp file.
Only the LNK2019 issues are left now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those users who may find this question in the future, here is what helped me:

1. Separating all classes
2. Adding `#pragma managed` to the an unmanaged wrapper for the actual class (got rid of the LNK2028)
3. One of the following commits:

   - [Moving invalidly placed C method out of `external "C"` that is not involved in any way normally to the static library built but MAY intefere with the CLR build process as the header still was there](https://github.com/SQFvm/vm/commit/3317dd75a490d09047ea2db61b68cdc0f0b983df)
   - [Altering the arangement of the constructor](https://github.com/SQFvm/vm/commit/36bd278a8ca1faff9bf5d5a65860c16e9a2e7ff4)

Hope this helps you.